# Converting current role based procedural php site to MVC and ACL

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I currently have a project where a procedural PHP site with an odd role based setup needs to be rewritten in MVC (probably codeigniter as I am new to MVC) and I can't quite get my head around the best way to proceed.

The current site uses sort of a front controller that checks the security level for the logged in user in the db, and builds the pages based on a directory structure that mirrors the security levels.

i.e.

Dir structure:

```
root
    -admin (sees everything and everyone elses subordinates)
        -- Reports listing managers, and their users
        -- CRUD for managers and their reports
        -- CRUD for users and their reports (types listed below)
    -manager (has users as subordinates, and can see all data related to them)
        -- Reports listing the manager's users
        -- CRUD for users and their reports (types listed below)
    -user (Can only see their own information)
        -- Reports listing the users information (lists, calendars, calls, etc.)
        -- CRUD for users reports (types listed above)
```

db user table psuedo

```
1 = admin
2 = manager
3 = user

UserAccountTable
    id
    pass
    user
    email
    security level (1,2,3)

manager Table
    manager ID
    User Account ID
    other fields containing personal info

user Info Table
    user Info id
    User Account ID
    Manager ID
    other fields containing personal info
```

front controller pseudo

```
load header
load menu
determine level from db
    if 1 load requested file from admin folder
    if 2 load requested file from manager folder
    if 3 load requested file from user folder
load footer
```

Main Question:

Are there any inherent issues in the current design that stand out (let me know if you need more specifics on current structure in order to answer)?

Given the structure above for the current site, what would be a solid approach for redesigning security using the current top down type of security (1 sees 2 and 3, 2 sees 3, 3 sees only 3) in an MVC structure, and is it possible with minimal changes to the db?

I'm not looking for code (although if anyone knows of something like this that I can look at to glean some understanding, that would be helpful), but more of a conceptual understanding of the process.

Comment: Symfony2 has really great built in ACL support (alongside roles) and is a much more solid framework than CodeIgniter, which is dated and, IMHO, ugly. Having said that, There's nothing in your pseudocode that stands out as bad practice or wrong.

Comment: @David thanks. But that brings up another concern of mine. Being new to MVC I get the impression that a loosely coupled or glue framework is more my style, but don't really know if it is the better than a full stack for my situation. So, first, if you don't mind my asking, what makes CI ugly, and why do you prefer S2?

Comment: It's based on a 6.5 year old version of PHP and therefore is missing namespaces, traits, closures, and many other features. They promote the use of short tags (nitpicking here) and I dislike the coding style. It really is just personal opinion though, it might be beneficial for you that it's backwards compatible with something that came out when I was in elementary school. In terms of simplicity, I think most of the major frameworks are at the same level with the exception of lithium and cake. The real question is the features that _you_ need. You might want a light FW like MicroMVC.

Comment: Look at how [ciBonfire](http://cibonfire.com) do their permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The current design has some limitations. The number of roles has been fixed and the permissions also fixed for the roles. The better way to design this will be in the following way.

```
User Table
----------
id
password
email
.....

permissions Table
-----------------
id
name

roles Table
-----------
id
name

user_roles Table
----------------
userid
roleid

roles_permission
----------------
roleid
permissionid
```

In the above table design, it is possible to assign permissions to roles then the roles can be assigned to users. Then the writing some helper functions such as hasPermission() can decide if the logged user has the needed permission to access something. For more performance it is possible to create some views to display user's permission and query on the view and check if user has the permission.

I have followed the same approach while designing the codeigniter website generator at [www.thephpcode.com](http://www.thephpcode.com). You can create a demo and check the admin portal for free to see how it is working in UI.

Comment: This has some merit, but doesn't allow for grouping of subordinates, and calls for some pretty drastic changes in th db structure. Your website is interesting though. Thanks for the link.

Comment: User roles can be used for grouping users. But in this implementation one user can have more roles as per the current design. But while using the system admin can create three roles has to make sure to assign one role per user.